Issues with React Native Navigation Persistence Despite Multiple Troubleshooting Steps
I have been facing persistent issues with React Native navigation for the past 10 days. As a beginner in React Native, I initially encountered errors while using React Native navigation. To troubleshoot, I switched to using Expo, but the errors persisted. In an attempt to resolve the problem, I even reinstalled Windows and the React Native CLI, but despite these efforts, the issues have not gone away.
I have attached a screenshot of the error for reference. Any guidance or advice from the community would be greatly appreciated.This is the error
I installed all required dependencies.
I want solution......

Have you installed react-native-gesture-handler? Can you post the contents of your package.json file?

@Taarna Yes I installed react-native-gesture-handler. This is package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.18.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.8",
"react-native-screens": "^3.34.0"
}

Are importing gesture handler at your app entry point?
